# Node-RED HTTP request node and string parameters

Tags: httprequest, node-red

I am trying to use the build-in HTTP request node to put in a localhost GET request. However, I am having trouble with escaped characters. The request URL should be of the following form:

```
localhost:port/path?param="{{payload}}"
```

I can successfully get the string part in, however I can't get the enclosing quotation marks right, they keep getting transformed to HTML numbers in the request. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Quote characters need to be URL encoded to be included in a Query parameter. See this [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) article for a list of encodings.

The correct way to encode double quotes `"` is as `%22`. Depending on what is processing  the values on the receiving end you may need to  decode them as well. The correct way to this in Node.JS is to use the `decodeURIComponent()` function.

Comment: How do I incorporate the decodeURIComponent function inside a HTTP request?

Comment: You don't in a HTTP-request and you shouldn't need to in a HTTP-in node as it should decode incoming query parameters for you

Comment: Also are you 100% sure you need the `"` around the query parameter?

Comment: Yes, the receiving application requires it. I have managed to do so using \", everything is working now (without decodeURIComponent() btw).